# Self host private chat room server

Tags: gratis, linux, chat, encryption, web-server

What are my options for hosting a private chat room server for <10 people (my family)?

Should I use a web server in combination with a chat component? Or an IRC server with a web interface component? Or something else?

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Runs on Linux.
- Hosts a web interface.

  - Makes a sound when the chat tab is inactive and a message arrives.
- Uses an encrypted connection (e.g., SSL)
- Uses login credentials that I (the host) define in a file.

Comment: So login credentials in let's say a MySQL database would not work out?

Comment: @Tom That's ok, but unnecessary for such a small amount of data. It's only 10 name/password combinations.

Comment: I've found rocket.chat. That might be a possibility.

Comment: I've used rocket chat, it's very similar to slack

Comment: With the web interface part, I suggest https://matrix.org along with https://riot.im ... it's federated, so you can even decide to connect to others later on, like you'd be able to do with XMPP (Jabber) as well. It's open source in addition to the requirements you put up. Not sure about your last requirement, though.